# User activation mail not working after a while

Tags: users, emails, activation

Does anyone know how much time a user has to use the activation link in the user activation mail?
Some clients report to us that that they see an error page after waiting a weekend to use the activation link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is determined by the [`defaultTokenDuration` general config setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#defaulttokenduration) which is set to 1 day unless you change it in the `general.php` config file.

Comment: We typically change ours to 14 days, which is a far more reasonable window for people to log in for the first time.